# Cannot access repository base class methods

Tags: c#, inheritance, repository-pattern, structuremap

In my specific repository classes for example CollectionRepository, i inherit the generic base class (BaseRepository) and in the constructor use the base UnitOfWork which should be injected. I however cannot access any of the BaseRepository inherited methods.

Completely out of ideas, any help would be appreciated.

Heres some code to illustrate my problem:

My controller where the repository is injected.

```
public readonly ICollectionRepository _collectionRepository;

public HomeController(ICollectionRepository collectionRepository, IRepository<Collection> repository)
{
  _collectionRepository = collectionRepository;
}

public ActionResult Index()
{
  _collectionRepository. //Here i only get the ICollectionRepositoryMethods

  return View(new List<Note>());
}
```

My base repository:

```
public class BaseRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : IAggregateRoot
{
  public readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

  public BaseRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
  {
    _unitOfWork = unitOfWork; 
  } 

  public BaseRepository()
  {}

  public void Save(T Entity)
  {
    _unitOfWork.Session.Save(Entity);
  }
}
```

And heres the specific repository class which inherits the base.

```
public class CollectionRepository : BaseRepository<Collection>, ICollectionRepository
{
  public CollectionRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) : base(unitOfWork)
  {
  }

  public IList<Collection> GetTodaysCollections()
  {
    throw new System.NotImplementedException();
  }
}
```

I am configuring the CollectionRepository like this with structuremap, not sure if this is correct:

```
For<ICollectionRepository>().Use<CollectionRepository>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce an interface for the BaseRepository that the ICollectionRepository implements.

This will let anything that is dealing with ICollectionRepository know about the BaseRepository methods.

```
public interface IBaseRepository<T>
{
    void Save(T Entity);
}
```

and BaseRepository implements that:

```
public class BaseRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T>, IRepository<T> where T : IAggregateRoot
```

Now when `ICollectionRepository` implements that interface all classes that in turn implement `ICollectionRepository` also implement `IBaseRepository`.

```
public ICollectionRepository<T> : IBaseRepository<T>
{
    //ICollectionRepository methods go here...
}
```

Because your `CollectionRepository` inherits from `BaseRepository` which implements the `IBaseRepository` interface, you already meet the requirements, and can now call the base class methods.

Comment: @David Hall Sorry for the late reply, I already have a base interface like you suggested, i just called it IRepository<t> (it should be called IBaseRepository<T> for clarity). Any other suggestions?

Comment: @geepie does your ICollectionRepository also implement IRepository? That is the main suggestion in my answer.

Comment: @David Hall no it doesn't, but it doesnt need to, i have done this before and used the generic methods in the BaseRepository rather than having to implement the interface(IRepository<T>) again in my specific CollectionRepository

Comment: @geepie perhaps you can pop onto chat? I'm in the C# room

Comment: @geepie basically passing in as an ICollectionRepository you do **not** have a CollectionRepository, so it does not matter that CollectionRepository inherits from BaseRepository, since ICollectionRepository does not have any of the BaseRepository's methods. This is why I suggest adding those methods to ICollectionRepository, by implementing the interface that gives them to BaseRepository. I don't know of any other way to access these methods when dealing with ICollectionRepository (well, beyond casting which entirely defeats what you are trying to do with using DI)

Comment: @David Hall HI david thanks for your help so far. I think i have found an example by Scott Millet doing what i suggested earlier or something similar. What do you think:  [link]http://www.elbandit.co.uk/projects/NhibernateCSharp.zip

Comment: @geepie - yes, so what they do is essentially the same as my suggestion. their IOrderRepository implements IRepository, OrderRepository inherits BaseRepository, and BaseRepository also implements IRepository.

Comment: @David Hall - Silly me i forgot to implement the IRepository as you suggested. I could of swore that i did! I will blame the early hours. thanks for all your help.